# Rails rendering nested comments use eager loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, nested, polymorphism, rendering

I wanted to be able to allow users to add comments to recipes. I also wanted users to be able to comment on those comments. It appears to be working, but maybe there are too many queries going on. I have researched and seen a lot of closely related articles, but none seem to be helping the issue. No matter how I change it up, it doesn't work. I can make as many comments on comments as I want, but as soon as there are multiple comments to a recipe it crashes. It's like I can have one or the other, but not both or it will crash. Here is what I have so far:

comment.rb

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end
```

recipe.rb

```
class Recipe < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
```

`recipes/show.html.erb`

```
<div class="">
  <h5>Comments:</h5>
  <div class="comment-form">
    <hr />
    <h3 class="subtitle is-3">Leave a reply</h3>
    <%= render @recipe.comments %>
  </div>
  <%= simple_form_for([@recipe, @recipe.comments.build]) do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
      <div class="control">
        <%= f.input :content, input_html: { class: 'input' }, wrapper: false, label_html: { class: 'label' } %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <%= f.button :submit, 'Leave a reply', class: "button is-primary" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

_comments.html.erb

```
<div class="box">
  <article class="media">
    <div class="media-content">
      <div class="content">
        <p>
          <strong><%= comment.content %></strong>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="">
    <%= form_for([comment, comment.comments.build]) do |f| %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :recipe_id, value: @recipe.id %>
      <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Add a Reply" %><br/>
      <%= f.submit "Reply"  %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= render comment.comments %>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I remove `<%= render comment.comments %>` It works, but obviously will not show me the comments on other comments. If I make only 1 comment on a recipe, I can comment on that comment as many times as I want with no issues. If I add just one more comment on the recipe, it crashes. If I pry in, it works and shows every comment is there until it is done going through each comment, then crashes. I know there are gems for this, but I am learning and really wanted to build from scratch and understand what is going on. Thanks in advance!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think if you made a self referential relationship on your Comment model it would work. You'd need to add a `parent_id` or whatever you want to call it. You can keep the polymorphic owner in case you have other models that will be able to have comments.

```
# Migration
def change
  add_column :comments, :parent_id, :integer, foreign_key: true
  add_index :comments, :parent_id
end
```

And then in your Comment model:

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Comment', inverse_of: :replies

  has_many :replies, foreign_key: :parent_id, class_name: 'Comment', inverse_of: :parent
end
```

If you're using Rails 5, you'd need to add `optional: true` to the `belongs_to :parent` relationship.